# PHP Foreach problems

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I have an array `$papers`, that comes from a database. The size of the array can change at the will of whoever changes the database.

I thought that if I did something like:

```
foreach($papers as $paper) {
    echo '<option value="' . $paper . '">' . $paper . '</option>';
}
```

I could get a dynamic list in my form. However, for some reason when I try this, the webpage just comes up blank. Obviouslly I could do something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < SOME_NUMBER; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $papers[$i] . '">' . $papers[$i] . '</option>';
}
```

But with the size of the array being variable, it doesn't seem like a viable option.
Also, when I use the second method of a simple for loop, the page loads, and the values do actually come up. I'm very confused as to why that is though. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Do `print_r($papers)` and see what you get.

Comment: Option 1 is fine. What does print_r($papers); give you? Blank page means you need to turn on error reporting.

Comment: heres a couple of things that might help get it sorted.  firstly try counting out how many results are in $papers  'echo count($papers);' also echo "<pre>"; print_r($papers); echo "</pre>";  your foreach should work fine.

Comment: Also, `php -l filename.php` to check it for parse errors.

Comment: "The webpage comes up blank" sounds like you have error reporting disabled. You could try `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` **Remember to disable it again after you are done degugging**

Comment: Do you have the `<select>`?  Turn `error_reporting` on and up, Like Ke$ha's hot pants.

Comment: Weird. The thing that actually ended up working was `php -l filename.php`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`, 'nuff said...

Answer (score 2):

you can modify your `foreach` loop like this

```
foreach($papers as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

where `$key` is holding the index and `$value` is holding actual value of array

i am not sure what data u are getting in your `$papper` array but i am guessing u can also do like this

```
foreach($papers as $paper) {
    echo '<option value="' . $paper['your_db_field_name'] . '">' . $paper['your_db_field_name'] . '</option>';
}
```

with simple `for loop` you can use `sizeof()` like below

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= sizeof($pappers) ; $i++){
//your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the array referencing method, try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($papers); $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $papers[$i] . '">' . $papers[$i] . '</option>';
}
```

The count() function will return the length of the array which, as you say, may be different each time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

turn on the error reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
init_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

and try to debug with :

```
print_r($papers);
```

and look the structure of the array $papers